# With Apache Collections4 Multikey what does unchecked call mean and how do I fix it?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, collections

I am changing a HashMap to use a MultiKey inside of a class.

Before:

```
 HashMap<String, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Now my key depends on 2 strings, so I'm using:

```
 HashMap<MultiKey, MyObject> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put(key(s1,s2),obj);

 private static MultiKey key(String s1, String s2) {
     return new MultiKey(s1,s2);
 }
```

IntelliJ highlights the constructor call to `MultiKey` and tells me the following:

```
Unchecked call to 'MultiKey(K,K)' as a member of raw type 'org.apache.commons.collections4.keyvalue.MultiKey
Signal places where an unchecked warning is issued by the compiler.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using raw types which provide less type-safety than non-raw types.

```
private static MultiKey key(String s1, String s2) {
    return new MultiKey(s1,s2);
}
```

Here the return type is a raw type `MultiKey`. Try changing it to its parameterized counterpart `MultiKey<String>`:

```
private static MultiKey<String> key(String s1, String s2) {
    return new MultiKey<>(s1,s2);
}
```

Also, your map definition uses raw type as well. Change it to

```
Map<MultiKey<String>, Descriptor> map = new HashMap<>();
```

Note that it's better to use an interface (`Map`) when declaring a map variable and not a concrete class (`HashMap`) in this case.

Comment: `Map<MultiKey<String>, MyObject>>` while I made this change also, what does it prevent happening? Because I'm not getting any warnings for that.  Thanks.

Comment: If your variable is defined as `Map<MultiKey, MyObject>`, you can put any `MultiKey` as a key, for example, `MultiKey<Integer>`. Later, you could try to extract a component from that key with `(String) entry.getKey().getKey(0)` expecting it to be a `String`. But as it would be an `Integer`, the cast would fail in runtime; that's the reason the compiler warns you.